# Browsers won't send stored cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

Below are the response headers I send from my server backend on a login request. The server is running on localhost:8090 and I'm serving the site from localhost:3000 using react-scripts. Both Chrome and Firefox store the cookie for the 'site' http://localhost:3000. I'm using axios to send API requests as shown below. The problem is that subsequent api requests do not send the cookie. From searching around I believe that the port is not supposed to make a difference, so the question is why is the cookie not being set?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 42
Set-Cookie: appcredentials=gXXXXXBb7GukifOC_xoQrQAEilZ6MlKa2IbNAPo9HIiIvw97qCpqUnBPfcdBp-o4eZVAXkCPVNfCFMFTlr-mi5-Ie9FkCg3BO-PGw-3sfDL3dPKA66vNNevK9089C7DCkBMwYpEcz3dm5HVcHVTXQVRk9M2oBNrDzXhczfhJFI_gubdYDt2BKjRCx6bRUkfgPEV_N-VyKmbR; Domain=localhost; Path=/
userId="gh@gh.com"; expires=Wed, 28 Nov 2018 18:38:06 GMT; Path=/
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2018 18:35:36 GMT
Server: Python/3.5 aiohttp/2.2.5
```

The axios call:

```
export const get_features = (callback) => async dispatch => {
  console.log('get the features man', cookie.load('appcredentials'))
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'http://localhost:8090/app/features',
      null,
      {withCredentials:true}
    );
    dispatch({ type: GET_FEATURES, payload: response.data });
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: e });
  }
};
```

Incidentally the console.log correctly logs the value of the cookie.